# Database call within a loop?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

An order object that has a property named products which is an array of objects which are products ordered.Within the object of products there is productId and quantity ordered.When each order is placed i want to extract the products and quantity ordered then make database calls to update stock levels on each object of product ordered.

I have sussefully extracted the productIds but when i place the database call to retrive each productId order then to subtract from the stocklevels each of the quantity of products ordered ..The While i have the productIds when i place my database call for retrival of each productId the database is returning null.

```
for (const product of newOrder.products) {
                const { productId, quantity } = product;

                if (productId && quantity) {
                    const stockItem: any = await StockItem.findOne({ productId: productId });
                    console.log(stockItem)
                    if (!stockItem) {
                        console.log(`No StockItem found for productId: ${productId}`);
                        // Handle this case, e.g., by returning an error response
                        continue; // Skip this product and proceed to the next one
                    }
}
```

returning

```
null
No StockItem found for productId: 20
null
No StockItem found for productId: 40
```

Comment: Does it work if you hardcode the `productId` like `await StockItem.findOne({ productId: 20 });`?